# getSupportFragmentManager() giving null

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display the maps but the google map is null. My code is-:

```
supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.add_event_map);

supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

         mgoogleMap = googleMap;
     }
});

mgoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

I am getting null pointer exception in the last line -:

```
mgoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: `mgoogleMap` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to wait for `onMapReady` call, only after that `mgoogleMap` will not be `null`

```
 @Override
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
     mgoogleMap = googleMap;
     mgoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Zoom controls once map is ready.

```
supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.add_event_map);

supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

         mgoogleMap = googleMap;

mgoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
     } });
```

Answer (score 0):

`mgoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true)` is executed before `onMapReady`.
You should add the code inside `onMapReady`.